# Pre- and post-notes at citations with supercite (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `\supercite` with biblatex for a numeric superscripted citation style.  Prenotes and postnotes are, as per the manual, discarded.  Is there any simple way to add them back in?

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
Text\supercite[prenote][postnote]{A01,B02}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the definition of `\supercite` from your `.cbx` file and add the calls to the relevant bibmacros back in.

For `numeric` (which is used if no explicit `style` is given) we need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\supercite[prenote][postnote]{sigfridsson,worman}
\end{document}
```

[image: "Text" followed by superscript "prenote 1,2, postnote"]

As shown in the output the risk is that the notes could visually overwhelm the small citation numbers, on the other hand there is a risk that at small font sizes the notes would be hard to read.

---

For `numeric-comp` as requested in the comments you would need

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a little more complicated with my default `numeric-comp` but I `numeric` will do for this document.

Comment: @ChrisH Have a look at the edit, please. For MWEs with `biblatex` it often makes sense to keep the style and not simplify it down to the default `style=numeric`. Especially when the question is about the output and behaviour of specific `\cite...` commands.

Comment: Further thanks.  It does sound like my MWE was a little too M. I've played around with the more accessible parts of biblatex but never had to get far enough in to have even seen a `.cbx` file so I've learnt something about the structure as well.

Comment: @ChrisH Since it is sometimes hard to say from the outset whether or not the style used is relevant to the question (or the answer) and adding (at least a standard) style usually does not complicate the issue much further, I recommend to err on the side of including the style in an MWE. If the style does not matter for the answer it is usually easily excluded, but if it does matter and is not known, then one has to guess.