# Change style of chem-angew .cbx in biblatex to add pre- and postnote in \auto- or \supercite

Tags: biblatex, citing, bibliographystyle

What is the correct way to add a `prenote` and `postnote` to the `\supercite` or `\autocite` operation using chem-angew style?

I looked for the .cbx file [here](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/blob/main/chem-angew.cbx) and the default is

```
  \newcommand*\mkbibsuperbracket[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
}
  
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperbracket]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}
```

I also looked at the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474366/pre-and-post-notes-at-citations-with-supercite-biblatex), but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case, someone had the same problem, I had a deeper look into the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474366/pre-and-post-notes-at-citations-with-supercite-biblatex?noredirect=1&lq=1) and modfied the cod a bit: `prenote` and `postnote` for `supercite` can be added by modifying the `\DeclareCiteCommand` in the .cbx file using

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperbracket]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```